# Import form csv files to outlook calendar error

Tags: outlook-calendar

[Outlook calendar does not recognize the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCHPc.png)

I used the data exported form my python code and turn the data into the csv file. After seeing the outlook calendar doesn't recognize it, I tried to use define name and add filters in excel and turn the xlsx file into the csv file but those doens't work either.
How can i fix this problem?
Please help me